# Save Python console output to Java variable

Tags: java, python, processbuilder

I have problem with saving python script's output to java variable. My code looks like...

Python script:

```
def main(argv):

    filepath = argv[1]
    ...
    output = results.get_forecast(14).predicted_mean.to_json()
    print(output)
    
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main(sys.argv)
```

And it works - results are printed to console - everything's fine.

My Java code:

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("python", "-u",
                "path/to/script.py", args_filepath).inheritIO();

        try {
            Process p = pb.start();

            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
            StringBuilder predictionString = new StringBuilder();
            String line;

            while((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                predictionString.append(line);
            }

            int exitCode = p.waitFor();
            System.out.println("VALUE: " + predictionString.toString());
            br.close();

        } catch (IOException | InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

That part also works... I mean it works in a way that it executes the python's code, writes output to console, but it doesn't save the output string to the `predictionString`.

Comment: What do you believe [`inheritIO()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html#inheritIO--) does, and why do you believe that? --- What do you believe [`p.getInputStream()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#getInputStream--) does when I/O is inherited, any why do you believe that? *Hint:* "If the standard output of the subprocess has been redirected using ProcessBuilder.redirectOutput then this method will return a **null input stream**."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `redirectErrorStream` method to capturing `output` stream.

```java
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("python", "-u",
                    "path/to/script.py", args_filepath)
                    .redirectErrorStream(true);
```

instead of

```java
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("python", "-u",
                "path/to/script.py", args_filepath).inheritIO();
```

Comment: wow - it works, thank you so much! need to read more about that